# How to write this code shorter and so that it may be used for a wider purpose?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple search engine, which is supposed to give out separate parameters of one Data unit. Is there a better (shorter) way you would write this?

````
type Qualification = [QualAttrib]
type QualAttrib    = String
type Name          = String
type Type          = String
type Provider      = String

num1000101 :: Qualification
num1000101 = ["Mathematics","BSc","UCL"]

getQualName a = a !! 0
getQualType a = a !! 1
getProvider a = a !! 2```
````

Comment: You should use a record here, it does not make sense at all to use a list, since your list contains different concepts (that *happen* to have the same type).

Answer (score 4):

It does not make much sense to use a list in the first place. A list should be used for a colleciton of items. But here `"Mathematics"` (the `Name`), and `"BSc"` (the `Type`) are orthogonal items. They only "*happen*" to have the same type. If you would later change the type of one of your items, then you can not even use a list (or at least not without using sum types, and that would make it even more ugly).

You better use a record for this, like:

```
data Qualification = Qualification {
    qualName :: Name,
    qualType :: Type,
    qualProvider :: Provider
}

type Name = String
type Type = String
type Provider = String
```

Now you can create a `Qualification` as:

```
num1000101 :: Qualification
num1000101 = Qualfication "Mathematics" "BSc" "UCL"
```

or more verbose:

```
num1000101 :: Qualification
num1000101 = Qualification {
    qualName="Mathematics",
    qualType="BSc",
    qualProvider="UCL"
  }
```

The nice thing is that the compiler generated functions for you: `qualName :: Qualification -> Name`, `qualType :: Qualification -> Type`, and `qualProvider :: Qualification -> Provider`, so there is no need to implement "getters" yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My original version might have been because I'm still not very at ease with data constructor techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Use record syntax

```
data Qualification = Qualification { name :: String
                                   , qtype :: String  -- type is reserved word
                                   , provider :: String}  deriving (Show, Eq)

num1000101 = Qualification "Mathematics" "BSc" "UCL"
```

now you have functions `name`,  `qtype` and `provider` which work as getters

```
> name num1000101
=> "Mathematics"
```